# Units on x axis of graph do not have the same scale

Tags: python, graph

I have the following code

```
import numpy as np

#x axis
data = open("spectra.dat","r")
linesColumn = data.readlines()
xaxis = []
for x in linesColumn:
    xaxis.append(x.split()[0])
data.close()

#y data
data = open("spectra.dat","r")
linesColumn1 = data.readlines()
firstColumn = []
for x in linesColumn1:
    firstColumn.append(x.split()[1])
data.close()

plt.plot(xaxis, firstColumn)

plt.show()
```

The data is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/177kzRGXIoSKvH1fC9XJZubfK3AHzHsFF/view?usp=sharing

When I plot the graph I get a linear function because the units on the x axis do not scale the same way. In the beginning one unit is 0.1 and in the end it's 5, but it's still displayed as the same distance on x axis.

How do I fix that?
Also, is there a way to optimize the column splitting (doing it through loop or something) and storing each column as one list?

Comment: You need to give permission to access data in google drive. By finding max and value of x-axis, we can use np.arange() function. For example np.arange(0, 5, 0.1): min val: 0, max val: 5, step_size: 0.1, by using this function we can have equal step size from starting point to the end

Comment: The data is now accesible, sorry.
That doesn't solve the problem for x axis (np.arange(xaxis)); "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `xaxis` consists of `str` type variables. By converting `str` type variable to `float` we can get expected figure. Code is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#x axis
data = open("spectra.DAT","r")
linesColumn = data.readlines()
xaxis = []
for x in linesColumn:
    xaxis.append(float(x.split()[0]))
data.close()

#y data
data = open("spectra.DAT","r")
linesColumn1 = data.readlines()
firstColumn = []
for x in linesColumn1:
    firstColumn.append(x.split()[1])
data.close()

plt.plot(xaxis, firstColumn)

plt.show()
```

[image]